# Creating Annotations from point features using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, annotation

Because in ArcGIS 10.0 there is still no simple toolbox function to convert labels to Annotation, I try to go a substitude way with the callable Toolbox function **[TiledLabelsToAnnotation][1]** on a polygon shape, which covers all of my data area (= 1 polygon).

---

The script is now running, because of the simplifications for the posting!

```
import arcpy

# Settings
scale = "30000"  
folder = "D:\Temp\LBL.gdb"  
arcpy.env.workspace = folder  

# Mapdocument
map = r"D:\Temp\MAP-LBL.mxd"  

# Local variables:
dataFrame = "Layer"  
grid = "Grid"  
group = "Group"  
suffix = "Anno"  
fid = "tile"  
link = "STANDARD"  # not linked = "STANDARD" / linked = "FEATURE_LINKED"   
unplace = "GENERATE_UNPLACED_ANNOTATION"  

# Process: Tiled Labels To Annotation
arcpy.TiledLabelsToAnnotation_cartography(map, dataFrame, grid, folder, group, suffix, scale, "", fid, "", "", link, unplace)
```

Comment: Please post your script.  It is impossible for us to figure out what is causing the error if we cannot see what you have.  It sounds like a syntax problem if you can run it manually and in Model Builder.